# I want to retrieve the last value of a column from the SQL SERVER database and store it in a variable and display it through a label

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to retrieve the last value of a column from the SQL SERVER database and store it in a variable and display it through a label. Table name is classes. There are two column
1. classid (int)
2. classname (varchar)
now i just want to retrieve last value of classid column and want to display it through a label in ASP.NET

How can i do.
I have written a connection string:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con1.Open();
SqlCommand check1 = new SqlCommand("select * from classes where classid=last(@classname)", con);
```

Comment: It's a too broad question. Where are you stuck exactly while solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1 Last supported only in MS Access
To get your classname and assign variable to this you need to do this

```
SqlCommand check1 = new SqlCommand("select classname from classes where classid=@classid", con);
```

and then

```
string className = (string)check1.ExecuteScalar();
```